# st_buffer with endCapStyle = "FLAT" and singleSide = TRUE not rendering correctly

Tags: r, buffer, terra, geos

I am trying to make a single sided buffer along ~600 transect lines, however the buffers are not working correctly.

[Incorrect single sided buffer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cojF2.jpg)

- I have tried implementing in both sf (v1.0-16) and terra (v1.7-71).
- I have projected from lat/lon to UTM Zone 10 (and tried Zone 9 with similar results)
- I have tried making the buffers with sf_use_s2(FALSE) and also sf_use_s2(TRUE)
- The sf and terra implementations both are similarly wrong.
- Oddly yesterday the code worked somewhat better with more of the transects getting a correct buffer (but not all of them!).

What am I missing!?

```
library(sf) #v1.0 -16
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(units)
library(terra)
library(tmap) 

#Linking to GEOS 3.11.0, GDAL 3.5.3, PROJ 9.1.0; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

#code for building the Linestring from full dataset - multipoint saved for trouble shooting
obs_pt<-obs %>% filter(is.na(Transect_ID)==FALSE)%>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), na.fail = FALSE, crs = "epsg:4326") %>%
  group_by(Transect_ID) %>%
  summarize() %>%
  filter(st_geometry_type(.) == "MULTIPOINT") 

obs_ls<-obs_pt %>% 
  st_cast("LINESTRING", keep=TRUE)

#switch from lat/lon to UTM for planer geometry
obs_ls_planer<-obs_ls%>%st_transform("EPSG:32610") #Zone 10= most of study area

#filter data for reproducible example:
obs_ls_125<-obs_ls_planer%>%filter(Transect_ID==125)

saveRDS(obs_ls_125,paste0(usr,dir,"obs_ls_125.rda"))

[obs_ls_125](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/47c83vgxeccphb1rkjumv/obs_ls_125.rda?rlkey=c1ymlbky7iohzhke6dap2x4ep&dl=0)

obs_ls_125<-readRDS("obs_ls_125.rda")

obs_ls_125
```

Simple feature collection with 1 feature and 5 fields
Geometry type: LINESTRING
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 361857.1 ymin: 4786302 xmax: 362981.9 ymax: 4787215
Projected CRS: WGS 84 / UTM zone 10N

## A tibble: 1 × 6

Transect_ID                                                 geometry Cruise_ID date       Condition ObsSidePS

- ```
    <int>                                         <LINESTRING [m]> <chr>     <date>     <chr>     <chr>
  ```

1         125 (362210.4 4786933, 362299.5 4786863, 362378.3 4786793, … 202210    2022-10-14 1         Starboard

```
#buffer implementation in sf
obs_ls_125.b <- st_buffer(obs_ls_125, dist = 100, endCapStyle = "FLAT", singleSide = TRUE)

#buffer implementation in terra
vsp <- terra::vect(obs_ls_125)
buffer_terra <- terra::buffer(vsp, width = 100, capstyle = "FLAT", singlesided = TRUE)
buffer_terra.sf <- sf::st_as_sf(buffer_terra)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = obs_ls_125.b, fill = "yellow")+
  geom_sf(data = obs_ls_125, color = "blue", linewidth = 1)+
  geom_sf(data = obs_ls_125.b%>%st_cast("POINT"), color = "orange") #points of polygon

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = buffer_terra.sf, fill = "pink")+
  geom_sf(data = buffer_terra.sf%>%st_cast("POINT"), color = "orange")
```

[plot of buffer from sf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pQ1rm.jpg)

[plot of buffer from terra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lt40D.jpg)

[plot of original GPS points colored by time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0dzO.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Not really, it works as expected, the *issue* is with the geometry of transects. Not a issue per se, but it's not a straight line which makes the thing harder. As you can see below, the buffer is onesided, however the line is bent, so with bigger buffer radius the polygon surrounds the whole line.

```r
a <- readRDS("~/Downloads/obs_ls_125.rda")
b <- a |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 30, singleSide = TRUE)

tmap::tm_shape(a) +
  tmap::tm_lines() +
  tmap::tm_shape(b) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_grid()
```

[image]

```r
b <- a |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 1000, singleSide = TRUE)

tmap::tm_shape(b) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_shape(a) +
  tmap::tm_lines() +
```

[image]

Here is a details of `linestring`:

```r
terra::plot(a["geometry"], axes = TRUE, 
            xlim = c(362450, 362550),
            ylim = c(4786650, 4786750))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

*Edit*

To deal with not straight transects is to simplify them. You can try `sf::st_simplify()` function with big enough `dTolerance = 1000` parameter, but it will move the most left/most right coordinates as well. Below simple approach how to create line just between most left/right coordinates and create buffer.
Don't know what your transect source is, kind of GPS file? If the line coordinates are given, then we have deal with it somehow; if that's something you can choose/create, then have a look on `sf::st_make_grid()` function.

```r
a <- readRDS("~/Downloads/obs_ls_125.rda")

crd <- a |>
  sf::st_coordinates()

xleft <- crd[which(crd[, "X"] == min(crd[, "X"])), "X"]
yleft <- crd[which(crd[, "X"] == min(crd[, "X"])), "Y"]

xright <- crd[which(crd[, "X"] == max(crd[, "X"])), "X"]
yright <-  crd[which(crd[, "X"] == max(crd[, "X"])), "Y"]

l <- matrix(c(xleft, yleft, xright, yright), nrow = 2, ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE) |>
  sf::st_linestring() |>
  sf::st_sfc()

b <- l |>
  sf::st_buffer(dist = 30, singleSide = TRUE)

tmap::tm_shape(l) +
  tmap::tm_lines(lwd = 3, col = "blue") +
  tmap::tm_shape(b) +
  tmap::tm_polygons() +
  tmap::tm_grid()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-03-27 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thank you! That is helpful, though I am surprised since I have seen buffers applied to odd-shaped polygons. Suggestions for a solution for not quite straight transects?

Comment: @rachaelorben, please have a look on edited answer, where a quite simple approach is shown.

Comment: Unfortunately it would be better to keep my not quite straight lines. I did find that overall the buffering worked better when I convert to a MULTILINESTRING - and am not sure why that is.

Comment: This example shows a working buffer with a much more convoluted line: https://spencerschien.info/post/spatial_buffer/